# Как записать в переменную уравнения с неизвестными параметрами для дальнейшего их нахождения?

Tags: python, математика

Вопрос звучит довольно запутано, сам понимаю. Сразу приведу пример своей программы, делаю оптимизацию функции по градиентному методу со сферической нормой, для этого
Задаю значения функций

```
def f(x, y):
    return pow(x, 2) + 3*pow(y, 2)

def dFx(x, y):
    return 2*x

def dFy(x, y):
    return 6*pow(y, 2)

def vec_len(x, y):
    return sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2))
```

Есть некая начальная точка

```
Xk = X0 = [2, 1]
```

И дальше идут подсчеты для нахождения коэфициентов:

```
len_dFk = vec_len(dFx(Xk[0], Xk[1]), dFy(Xk[0], Xk[1]))
Pk = [-dFx(Xk[0], Xk[1])/len_dFk, -dFy(Xk[0], Xk[1])/len_dFk]
```

И тут мне нужно найти значение альфа которое берется из следующего уравнения(тут псевдокод):

```
Xk[0] = Xk[0] + Pk[0]*α 
Xk[1] = Xk[1] + Pk[1]*α
```

И вот тут то мне и надо каким то образом записать это уравнение с неизвестным еще "α"(которое я в дальнейшем найду понятное дело), и вот вопрос в том как записать это уравнение в самом коде для его дальнейшего решения?

Comment: У вас производная `df/dy` неправильно записана.

Comment: Но ведь альфа - это коэффициент скорости градиентного спуска? Его надо задавать, а не вычислять. То есть, для выполнения операции очередного приближения, альфа должно быть уже известно.